# Flutter SteamBuilder throwing error on first argument context

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have a problem here with flutter (v2.8.1) on my windows.

I am trying to use StreamBuilder class to fetch data from firebase but it is not working anyhow. I tried to use BuildContext context but it is still throwing me error on context.

Please have a look at my code and let me know what I am doing wrong. Answers are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
StreamBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot), stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots()),
```

Error :

> The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>)'.

Please check the image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqUfc.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builder argument should be a function that returns a widget.

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  // return a widget that uses the snapshot
  // for example
  return Text(snapshot.data().title);
}
```

Comment: Giving me the same error. What am I doing wrong? Please see the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/S0tDfeb

Comment: You are not passing a function to`builder`. Please, check the updated answer.